# Facebook registration plugin integration in cakephp?

Tags: facebook, cakephp

in template:

```
<div><fb:registration redirect_uri=http://mydomain/users/register fields="name,birthday,gender,location,email" /></div>
```

In model and Controller, I have function register() in users model and controller

```
        define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', ''); // Place your App Id here
        define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', ''); // Place your App Secret Here


        // No need to change the function body
        function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) 
        {
        list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
        // decode the data
        $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
        $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);
        if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256')
        {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        return null;
        }


        // check sig
        $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
        if ($sig !== $expected_sig) 
        {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
        }
        return $data;
        }
        function base64_url_decode($input) 
        {
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
        }
        if ($_REQUEST) 
        {
        $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'],
        FACEBOOK_SECRET);


        $name = $response["registration"]["name"];
        $email = $response["registration"]["email"];
        $password = $response["registration"]["password"];
        $country = $response["user"]["country"];

        echo $country;


        echo $name;
        echo $email;
        echo $password;

        ...............
```

So its working fine and I am getting data from facebook. I want to integrate this code with my cakephp registration code.  I am very new to cakephp, so please if any body give me a link, how to integrate facebook registration plugin in cakephp?

Comment: Could you tell which docs/links you've already looked and why didn't those work for you?

Comment: I don't know how to integrate this code to my cakephp code, where I have user controller and model and already I have cakephp registration code available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/229/CakePHP_Facebook_Plugin_Auth_Facebook_and_more

It has many more features to implement various Facebook functionality like login, registration, share, comments etc.

I've used this for login functionality and its working fine.